# Recovering FragmentActivity after screen rotate

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, viewpagerindicator

I'm using ViewPagerIndicator library by Jake Wharton and in FragmentActivity shown below when I rotate the screen the onCreate method is called but the activity remains blank and only displays the indicators ('Tab 1' and 'Tab 2').

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Tab 1", "Tab 2", };

    ProgressDialog progress;

    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter;
    ViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Loading data...");

        new getData().execute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    class FragPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public FragPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if(position == 0){
                return FragmentTabOne.newInstance();
            }else if(position == 1){
                return FragmentTabTwo.newInstance();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return CONTENT.length;
        }

    }

    private class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //getting data from server

            return true;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

                setContentView(R.layout.main_activity); //indicator + viewpager

                adapter = new FragPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

                pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

                pager.setAdapter(adapter);

                TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
                indicator.setViewPager(pager);

                progress.dismiss();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

What should I do (probably in the onSaveInstanceState method) for the activity and its fragments to be displayed correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your fragments' `onCreateView()` try adding a call to `setRetainInstance(true)`